# Marketing cloud connect: unable to send to report as decribed in testing connection documentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm going through [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_test_the_connection.htm&type=5) guide in order to check if our connector is working fine, but I'm stuck with an issue I can't seem to solve.

By sending to a report as described in the aforementioned guide, the send gets stuck with a status of "Processing Data" and a "Retried creating send definition" as a message. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

I tried many times but I get the same result everytime.

Any idea on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see into both CRM and Marketing Cloud, answering this is difficult. One thing I would check is that the From Email Address that you are using for the send has been verified in Marketing Cloud in the From Address Management section. If it is not, then the send will continue to fail.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a send classification for the send with a verified email in the sender profile.